# Dropdown not able to select

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium webDriver. Below is the code which i used to select day, Month & Year from dropdown of Facebook.

```
public class Facebook { 
public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/Selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");          
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_1")).sendKeys("selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_3")).sendKeys("selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).sendKeys("1234567891");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_8")).sendKeys("1234567891");

        Thread.sleep(500);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='day']"))).selectByVisibleText("17");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month"))).selectByVisibleText("Aug");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year"))).selectByVisibleText("1988");

        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_i")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_e"));
```

Not able to select dropdown list. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide a lead since you have not captured all necessary details in code snippet.

```
WebElement selElem=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='day']")));
Select sel=new Select(selElem);
sel.selectByVisibleText("Aug");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

I have simply increase the `wait` after selecting the each value from `dropdown` selection.

**Note:-** If id is present inside the element, then use `id locator`, instead of using `xpath locator`.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day"))).selectByVisibleText("17");
Thread.sleep(1000);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month"))).selectByVisibleText("Aug");
Thread.sleep(1000);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year"))).selectByVisibleText("1988");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and it will work for you:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/Selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");          
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_1")).sendKeys("selenium");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_3")).sendKeys("selenium");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).sendKeys("1234567891");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_8")).sendKeys("1234567891");

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day"))).selectByVisibleText("17");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month"))).selectByVisibleText("Aug");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year"))).selectByVisibleText("1988");

driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_i")).click();
```

You have done a mistake in your code i.e. if you are using an implicit wait then you have to write it before your url launch. In your case you wrote it after url launch. Now copy and paste this code and it will definitely work.